# How to restrict Shiny fileInput to text files only?

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I want to restrict my file browser to displaying only the types of file I specify, e.g. .txt files only. The only relevant snippets of a code I found are like the following:

```
fileInput("in_file", 
          "Input file:",
          accept=c("txt/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".csv")
```

However, this does't filter the files showing in the browser to just .txt and .csv. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand, that's the right way to do it. If you view your app in the RStudio viewer it wouldn't do anything, but in a browser it should.  I'm using Chrome and I just ran that code and it did in fact only show me txt and csv files.

Of course the user can still choose to view other files by going to the little select box and choosing to view all files, but they have to consciously choose to do that. By default only csv and txt files will be shown

Comment: Thank you, you're right, it does more filtering in Chrome! However, in the drop-down it  shows "Custom Files" rather than ".CSV". Let me take another look at my code before I mark your answer as final...

Comment: Ok, so everything worked in the browser like you were suggesting. thank you. I used _accept = c("text", ".txt")_ for text files and _accept = c("csv", ".csv")_ for CSV files.

Comment: I think the "custom files" will still show up, but that's ok, if the user purposely tries to see other file types then he deserves to get an error :)

Comment: No, actually with the code in my previous comment it no longer shows Custom Files but "Text Files" and "Microsoft Comma Separated Values".

Comment: haha "microsoft" csv... Because I'm sure they patented that file format :) Glad it works

Comment: :) Actually, it says _Microsoft Excel Comma Separated..._. Thanks again for your help, daattali!